# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I get `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator` Error when I following contion to my where clause.

```
and (round(to_number(c.rest_time - a.TIME_STAMP) * 24 * 60 )) >  5
```

Full Where clause

```
From TableA a,TableB b
    where round(to_number(a.rest_time - a.time_stamp) * 24 * 60 )) >  5
    and a.time_stamp > '05-12-2014 22:00:00'
    and a.rest_time < '05-14-2014 14:00:00'
    and a.dev = 'CUSTOMER'
    and b.xid = a.xid
    and b.accno = a.accno 
    and b.name is not null 
    and b.dis is null
```

Comment: Can you post the full `WHERE` clause?

Comment: And the datatypes of the columns

Comment: Would you need to add TO_DATE to the a.time_stamp and a.rest_time fields?

Comment: The thing is the same condition I have in different but similar query and it doesn't throw error..

Comment: a.time_stamp > '05-12-2014 22:00:00'  Isn't that comparing a number to a string?

Comment: I have added this in altered session by using this  `alter session set nls_date_format='MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`

Comment: @DStanley Thanks it was good idea to post the full `WHERE` clause. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra right parenthesis . It should be `... where round(to_number(a.rest_time - a.time_stamp) * 24 * 60 ) >  5 ...`

For instance,

```
-- your case (throws  invalid relational operator ):
select 1 from dual where  round(to_number(sysdate- sysdate) * 24 * 60 )) >  5 ;

--corrected :
select 1 from dual where  round(to_number(sysdate- sysdate) * 24 * 60 ) >  5 ;
```

Comment: lol I feel bad even posting this question. It was a extra parenthesis, when I copied this condition from my other query. I probably missed to  copy `(`. Thanks again.